# Why does this loop only record the movement of offender agents who move left and up?

Tags: python, agent-based-modeling

I am writing code for a simplistic agent-based model. In this model, offenders "move" 6-8 cells in a randomly selected direction (options are 1=up, 2=right, 3=down, 4=left). This movement occurs on a 2D numpy array that is filled with the values 0, 1, 2, and 3.

The following loop (which will eventually be a function) is supposed to generate that motion. It works for offenders who move up and left but not for those who move down or right. This loop calls one other and I have included those below the loop.

The use of a previous_city to serve as a copy of the city may be part of the problem but I'm not sure. I need a copy of the city array to serve as a reference so that after an offender moves onto a cell and leaves it in the next iteration, I can then use this reference to assign the value that the cell was previous to the offender moving there.

I have found that this loop does find new points for offenders that "move" in all four directions. However, after finding the new point, it only "moves" the offenders who move up and left. Why is this?

```
##-- THE LOOP USED TO REASSIGN OFFENDERS TO A NEW POINT --## 
# defining new and previous city for reference in function
new_city = test_city.copy()
previous_city = test_city.copy()

for i in range(test_city.shape[0]):
    for j in range(test_city.shape[1]):

        # if cell in city is empty space:
            # it stays empty in new_city
        if test_city[i,j] == 0:
            new_city[i,j] = 0

        # if cell in city is a citizen 
            # it stays a citizen in new_city and doesn't move (booooo)
        elif test_city[i,j] == 1:
            new_city[i,j] = 1

        # if cell in city is capable guardian
            # it stays a guardian in new_city and doesn't move (boooo)
        elif test_city[i,j] == 3:
            new_city[i,j] = 3

            # if cell in city is offender 
        if test_city[i,j] == 2:

            ##-- FINDING NEW POINT FOR OFFENDER TO MOVE TO --##

            found_point = False
            while found_point == False:

                # select distance (6-8 cells) to be travelled 
                distance = np.random.randint(6,9) 

                # select direction to travel (north = 1, east = 2, south = 3, west = 4)
                direction = np.random.randint(1,5)

                # identify new_point based on distance and direction
                if direction == 1: # if new direction is north 
                    #new_point = city[i-distance,j]
                    new_point_i = i - distance
                    new_point_j = j
                    if onBoard(new_point_i, new_point_j, test_city) == True and test_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] != 2:
                        found_point = True
                        print(new_point_i, new_point_j)
                        new_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] = 2

                elif direction == 2: # if new direction is east
                    #new_point = city[i,j+distance]
                    new_point_i = i
                    new_point_j = j + distance
                    if onBoard(new_point_i, new_point_j, test_city) == True and test_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] != 2:
                        found_point = True
                        print(new_point_i, new_point_j)
                        new_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] = 2

                elif direction == 3: # if direction is south 
                    #new_point = city[i+distance,j]
                    new_point_i = i + distance
                    new_point_j = j
                    if onBoard(new_point_i, new_point_j, test_city) == True and test_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] != 2:
                        found_point = True
                        print(new_point_i, new_point_j)
                        new_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] = 2

                elif direction == 4: # if direction is west 
                    #new_point = city[i,j-distance]
                    new_point_i = i
                    new_point_j = j - distance
                    if onBoard(new_point_i, new_point_j, test_city) == True and test_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] != 2:
                        found_point = True
                        print(new_point_i, new_point_j)
                        new_city[new_point_i, new_point_j] = 2

            ##-- FILLING IN OFFENDER'S OLD LOCATION WITH PREVIOUS_CITY VALUE --## 

            ###-- checking value of offender's old location in previous_city --###

            # if value of offender's old location in previous_city was empty
                # set the cell's value in new_city to empty
            if previous_city[i,j] == 0:
                new_city[i,j] = 0

            # if value of offender's old location in previous_city was citizen
                # set the cell's value in new_city to a citizen
            elif previous_city[i,j] == 1:
                new_city[i,j] = 1

            # if value of offender's old location in previous_city was capable guardian
                # set the cell's value in new_city to a capable guardian
            elif previous_city[i,j] == 3:
                new_city[i,j] = 3

            # if value of offender's location in previous_city was offender
                # set the value in new_city to empty 
            elif previous_city[i,j] == 2:
                new_city[i,j] = 0


##-- FUNCTION TO CHECK IF NEW POSITION IS WITHIN THE BOUNDS OF THE ARRAY --##
def onBoard(i,j,image):
    if i <= image.shape[0]-1 and i >= 0 and j <= image.shape[1]-1 and j >= 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Sorry for the amount of code included. I did not know how else to communicate the problem effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! As is usually the case. I was being a dummy. When it assigns any offenders to a new position that is down or right, these new positions are then subject to reassignment when the loop reaches those new indices!

For example, in a 3x3 square, if I move a 2 from index 0,0 to 0,2 the loop will reassign that cell when it loops through the cell at index 0,2. In doing so it will erase the new offender because it assigns the cell's value based on the original city which has the offenders in the original positions!

The limits of my stupidity know no bounds!